# Scrapy: Dynamically generate rules for each start_url

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have created a spider which is supposed to crawl multiple websites and I need to define different rules for each URL in the start_url list.

```
start_urls = [
    "http://URL1.com/foo"
    "http://URL2.com/bar"
]

rules = [
    Rule (LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=("//" + xpathString+"/a")), callback="parse_object", follow=True)
]
```

The only thing that needs to change in the rule is the xpath string for restrict_xpath. I've already come up with a function that can get the xpath I want dynamically from any website.
I figured I can just get the current URL that the spider will be scraping and pass it through the function and then pass the resulting xpath to the rule.

Unfortunately, I've been searching and it seems that this isn't possible since scrapy utilizes a scheduler and compiles all the start_urls and rules right from the start. Is there any workaround to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using `CrawlSpider`.
By default, `CrawlSpider` `rules` are applied for all pages (whatever the domain) your spider is crawling.

If you are crawling multiple domains in start URLs, and want different rules for each domains, you wont be able to tell scrapy which rule(s) to apply to which domain. (I mean, it's not available out of the box)

You can run your spider with 1 start URL at a time (and domain-specific rules, built dynamically at init time). And run multiple spiders in paralel.

Another option is to subclass `CrawlSpider` and customize it for your needs:

- build `rules` as a dict using domains as keys,
  and values  being the list of rules to apply for that domain. See [`_compile_rules`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ebef6d7c6dd8922210db8a4a44f48fe27ee0cd16/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py#L81) method.
- and apply different rules depending on the domain of the response. See [`_requests_to_follow`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ebef6d7c6dd8922210db8a4a44f48fe27ee0cd16/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py#L51)

Answer (score 0):

You can just override the `parse` method. This method will get a scrapy response object with full html content. You can run xpath on it. You will can also retrieve the url from the response object and depending on the url, you can run custom xpath.

Please checkout the docs here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

Comment: Thanks, but I want the spider to follow links. Specifically, only those links that are relevant to the data that I need. That's why I explicitly defined the restrict_xpaths parameter.