# Dynamic rules based on start_urls for Scrapy CrawlSpider?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm writing a Scrapy scraper that uses CrawlSpider to crawl sites, go over their internal links, and scrape the contents of any external links (links with a domain different from the original domain).

I managed to do that with 2 rules but they are based on the domain of the site being crawled. If I want to run this on multiple websites I run into a problem because I don't know which "start_url" I'm currently on so I can't change the rule appropriately.

Here's what I came up with so far, it works for one website and I'm not sure how to apply it to a list of websites:

```py
class HomepagesSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'homepages'

    homepage = 'http://www.somesite.com'

    start_urls = [homepage]

    # strip http and www
    domain = homepage.replace('http://', '').replace('https://', '').replace('www.', '')
    domain = domain[:-1] if domain[-1] == '/' else domain

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=(domain), deny_domains=()), callback='parse_internal', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=(), deny_domains=(domain)), callback='parse_external', follow=False),
    )

    def parse_internal(self, response):

        # log internal page...

    def parse_external(self, response):

        # parse external page...
```

This can probably be done by just passing the start_url as an argument when calling the scraper, but I'm looking for a way to do that programmatically within the scraper itself.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Simon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640023/scrapy-dynamically-generate-rules-for-each-start-url) and used the second option presented in the accepted answer to develop a workaround for this problem, since it's not supported out-of-the-box in scrapy.

I've created a function that gets a url as an input and creates rules for it:

```py
def rules_for_url(self, url):

    domain = Tools.get_domain(url)

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=(domain), deny_domains=()), callback='parse_internal', follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=(), deny_domains=(domain)), callback='parse_external', follow=False),
    )

    return rules
```

I then override some of CrawlSpider's functions.

1. I changed _rules into a dictionary where the keys are the different website domains and the values are the rules for that domain (using `rules_for_url`). The population of _rules is done in `_compile_rules`
2. I then make the appropriate changes in `_requests_to_follow` and `_response_downloaded` to support the new way of using `_rules`.

```py
_rules = {}

def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
    if not isinstance(response, HtmlResponse):
        return
    seen = set()

    domain = Tools.get_domain(response.url)
    for n, rule in enumerate(self._rules[domain]):
        links = [lnk for lnk in rule.link_extractor.extract_links(response) 
                 if lnk not in seen]
        if links and rule.process_links:
            links = rule.process_links(links)
        for link in links:
            seen.add(link)
            r = self._build_request(domain + ';' + str(n), link)
            yield rule.process_request(r)

def _response_downloaded(self, response):

    meta_rule = response.meta['rule'].split(';')
    domain = meta_rule[0]
    rule_n = int(meta_rule[1])

    rule = self._rules[domain][rule_n]
    return self._parse_response(response, rule.callback, rule.cb_kwargs, rule.follow)

def _compile_rules(self):
    def get_method(method):
        if callable(method):
            return method
        elif isinstance(method, six.string_types):
            return getattr(self, method, None)

    for url in self.start_urls:
        url_rules = self.rules_for_url(url)
        domain = Tools.get_domain(url)
        self._rules[domain] = [copy.copy(r) for r in url_rules]
        for rule in self._rules[domain]:
            rule.callback = get_method(rule.callback)
            rule.process_links = get_method(rule.process_links)
            rule.process_request = get_method(rule.process_request)
```

See the original functions [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py#L56).

Now the spider will simply go over each url in start_urls and create a set of rules specific for that url. Then use the appropriate rules for each website being crawled.

Hope this helps anyone who stumbles upon this problem in the future.

Simon.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all website links in `start_urls` and populate `allowed_domains` and `deny_domains` arrays. And then define Rules.

```
start_urls = ["www.website1.com", "www.website2.com", "www.website3.com", "www.website4.com"]

allow_domains = []
deny_domains = []

for link in start_urls

    # strip http and www
    domain = link.replace('http://', '').replace('https://', '').replace('www.', '')
    domain = domain[:-1] if domain[-1] == '/' else domain

    allow_domains.extend([domain])
    deny_domains.extend([domain])


rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=allow_domains, deny_domains=()), callback='parse_internal', follow=True),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=(), deny_domains=deny_domains), callback='parse_external', follow=False),
)
```

Comment: No, the contents of external links ARE scraped. Internal links are not scraped, only crawled in order to find all external links on the website.

Comment: @Simon then you need to debug your Selectors in `parse_internal` .. they might be incorrect

Comment: How are they incorrect? I think you might have missed a paragraph in the question. I wrote in the question that the code IS working, I'm just looking for a way to apply this on multiple start_urls.

Comment: @Simon I am not sure what are you trying to ask! Do you want to crawl multiple URLs using same `Rule`? You can just put as many URls as you want in `start_urls` ... its actually a List (Array)

Comment: The rules use the `domain` variable. `domain` is based on `homepage`. `homepage` is what is used in `start_urls`. If I add another url to `start_urls`, by the time CrawlSpider gets to the second url, the rules aren't correct anymore, because they are based on the first url.

Comment: @Simon Ahhh ... thats easy.... I have edited my answer, please re-read my answer.

Comment: Your code uses all of the domains provided for the rules. I need the rules to be dynamic, according to the site currently being scraped. If the scraped the website is `www.website2.com` then `domain` that is used in the rules should be `website2.com`. If the scraped website is `www.website4.com` then `domain` should be `website4.com`... etc.

Comment: Thats not possible with `Rule` function, one thing you can do is inside  `parse_internal` write an if-statement to check if URL contains 'website1' or not  and so on

Comment: I've found a workaround, see the answer I provided if it interests you. Thanks for the help anyway :)