# Scrapy: follow external links only

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

With [`OffsiteMiddleware`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py) you can control how to follow external links in Scrapy.

I want the spider to **ignore all internal links** on a site and follow external links **only**.

[Dynamic rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42628134) to add the response URL domain to `deny_domains` didn't work.

Can you override `get_host_regex` in `OffsiteMiddleware` to filter out all onsite links? Any other way?

**Clarification**: I want the spider to ignore the domains defined in `allowed_domains` and all internal links on each domain crawled. So the domain of every URL followed by the spider must be ignored when the spider is on that URL. **In other words: When the crawler reaches a site like example.com, I want it to ignore any links on example.com and only follow external links to sites that are not on example.com.**

Comment: Is is important for you to scrape with Scrapy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create reverse offsite middleware by simply reversing `should_follow()` method:

```
#mycrawler.middlewares.py

from scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite import OffsiteMiddleware
from scrapy.utils.httpobj import urlparse_cached

class ReverseOffsiteMiddleware(OffsiteMiddleware):

    seen = set()

    def should_follow(self, request, spider):
        allowed_domains = not super().should_follow(request, spider)
        # if failed to pass reverse allowed_domains don't follow
        if not allowed_domains:  
            return False

        # if visited domain before do not schedule request
        domain = urlparse_cached(request).hostname
        if domain in self.seen:
            return False
        # otherwise add to seen domain set and schedule request
        self.seen.add(domain)
        return True
```

Then activate it in your `settings.py`:

```
# settings.py
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware': None,
    'mycrawler.middlewares.ReverseOffsiteMiddleware': 500,
}
```

Now all domains in `spider.allowed_domains` will be ignored :)

Comment: Will this only ignore the domains defined in `allowed_domains`? I want to ignore  internal links on each domain crawled, so every URL followed has to add its domain to `allowed_domains` dynamically.

Comment: yes you need to specify the domain manually. How else would you determine what is offsite? Do you mean relative urls? like `/foo.html` vs `http://example.com/foo.html` ?

Comment: My question is different, I added some clarification. When the crawler goes to a site like example.com, I want it to ignore any links on example.com and continue crawleing the external sites only.

Comment: @lecodesportif Interesting case. Could you post you crawler code? There are many ways of achieving this. You can do it with a middleware but ideally you would manage this in your crawler code itself unless you are using `CrawlSpider` and crawling rules.

Comment: @lecodesportif I've updated my answer. In this approach the middleware will block domains that are in `allowed_domains` and block domains that have been scheduled already which means only 1 request per domain.

Answer (score 0):

My answer doesn't use Scrapy.  Feel free to flag this response if you think it's too far off topic.

But what I'm providing is a solution to help solve your more general problem.

I ran into a similar problem when I was parsing results from google.  I didn't want any of the boilerplate urls that show up on the results page to be included in my final list of urls.  I also didn't want any of the google relate query strings to show up.  Using BeautifulSoup, re module, and the requests module I was able to do this.

For your problem I would say you only need BeautifulSoup and re.  You'll need a function that will filter domains.  The function should take two params, reference and the url under test.  Using the re module you can check to see if the test url base string is the same as the reference string; if yes then it would reasonable to conclude that it's an internal url.

You'd use BeautifulSoup to parse the html for `<a>` tags that contain an `href`.